# Synaptic install issue

Tags: libreoffice, synaptic

I am new to Ubuntu, I want to install LibreOffice,

- Ubuntu version 15.04.
- I tried installing Synaptic (synaptic_0.81.3_amd64.deb)
- I am not able to install Synaptic, I get the following error,

  ```
  synaptic: error while loading shared libraries: libvte2_90.so.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  ```

I did try to find answer in the forum, but I did not get any info, can some body help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to download Synaptic.

Use Ubuntu Software Center to install Synaptic or any other software.

If there is a reason why you do not want to use USC, just run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

But as soon as you already tried to install a correct version of Synaptic, you can fix the dependency problem by running

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

That will download and install the needed packages.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Pilot6 **absolutely correct answer**. The missing file is in the package `libvte-2.90-9`. Therefore you could also install the missing package via

```
sudo apt-get install libvte-2.90-9
```

and repair you package system via

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: That `ibvte-2.90-9` should be installed by `-f` automatically.

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, I wanted to deal only with the specific error.